# My metamask wallet was hacked and i need to change passphrase

Tags: ether, metamask, security, passphrase

I have been stolen two and more ethers today from my metamask passphrase.How can i change the passphrase of the ether wallet so i will be able to charge more ethers to this address?I have tokens and nfts and every time i am trying to load my account the guy that has stolen the pass phrase keeps taking them.

Comment: It is not possible. It is better to create a new seed phrase. If you want to recover tokens from the hacked address there are some services that provide help but it is quite complex an expensive without guarantee that it will work. Be careful you will get a lot of messages trying to help you but most of them will be scammers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what services would those be? I have never heard of something like this.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean service?It was metamask web wallet and someone stole the keys of my wallet....but i have many nfts and no gas to transfer them .....thats the problem...

Comment: I do know that is hard to do but if i can transfer all different nfts as a bulk or tranfer my wallet somehow....?

Comment: @KostiantynKurbatskyi I haven't used those services, but they usually something similar to flashbots, group several transactions so they are all mined together or they won't be mined.